# Get Int value from dymanic SQL using a DataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have the following code that is used the execute the dynamic SQL below.

```
sql = "DECLARE @RetVal int; EXEC @RetVal=[dbo].[Sproc];Select @RetVal AS RetVal;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var names = Enumerable.Range(0, rdr.FieldCount).Select(rdr.GetName).ToList();
    retVal = rdr.RecordsAffected;
}
```

No error is thrown, but the datareader contains only one record that literally contains the value "RetVal" as shown in the following:

[image: Returned datareader]

Removing the "As RetVal" from the dynamic SQL, just returns an empty string.

If I run the same dynamic SQL in SSMS, it does return an Int value.

How do I get the actual int value @RetVal from the dynamic sql?

I have looked at using rdr.GetInt32 function, but as index 0 is a string, it just fails.

Comment: Seems like you're after an `OUTPUT` parameter? Difficult to tell what is really going on here without the definition of `Sproc`.

Comment: If you're returning one row with one column, `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is your friend.